# jshint not found when run from TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, jshint

I installed jshint on my computer with:

```
npm install -g jshint
```

There were no errors.  From a command prompt in any directory typing:

```
jshint -v
```

shows:

```
jshint v2.6.0
```

I also have TeamCity 9.0.2 installed, and have a build configuration with this "Command Line" build step:

```
jshint -v
```

But the build fails and the build log says:

```
[17:43:06]Step 1/7: Command Line
[17:43:06][Step 1/7] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script1904467346557960405.cmd
[17:43:06][Step 1/7] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\494a4c7f8e6d54de
[17:43:06][Step 1/7] 'jshint' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[17:43:06][Step 1/7] operable program or batch file.
[17:43:06][Step 1/7] Process exited with code 1
[17:43:06][Step 1/7] Step Command Line failed
```

How can I get jshint to run from TeamCity?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new **Command Line Build Step** in TeamCity.Use the following there.

```
rm -rf $(pwd)/node_modules/*  #removing subfolders present in node_modules folder
rm -rf $(pwd)/bower_components/*  #removing subfolders present in bower_components folder 
npm cache clean
npm install  #auto detect and install all npm modules required for your project
npm install bower
npm install grunt-ftp-push --save-dev #if ftp push is required
bower install
grunt buildproduction
```

This build step alone would be enough.I hope this would work.